# ASP.NET, PHP, SQL Server, MySQL hosting provider for developer?

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am looking to find a web hosting provider that provides ASP.NET and PHP hosting. The purpose is pretty much just a programming playground for me to develop in and possible show some of my work.

As I use ASP.NET and PHP I am looking for a provider that provides hosting for both of these technologies as well as access to MS SQL Server and MySQL.

Of course I am on a budget so I really can't afford to pay more than $20/month. I had looked at M6.net however in scanning for reviews I found a good deal of negative feedback. I currently use DownTownHost.com and have a good experience with them, however they do not support ASP.NET.

I do not require email hosting though I know most packages include it anyway. Thanks for any suggestions.

Some features that are important to me:

```
* ASP.NET 4 hosting
* ASP.NET MVC support
* PHP
* MySQL
* SQL Server
* URL Rewrite support
* multiple sites under one account
```

Comment: Made CW, List of X.

Answer (score 4):

I think that http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx?ci=9009#details is a good source for what Godaddy is currently hosting.  However, I am fairly certain that they do not allow for URL Rewrite.  I know they didn't 2 months ago.

Also, GoDaddy just turned on .NET 4.0 and MVC 2 support.  It usually takes them 8+ months after release for them to upgrade their servers.  I also believe they are stilling running SQL Server 2005.

Also, any host running IIS7 should be able to support PHP as IIS7 and above support PHP (earlier versions could but I don't know).

Microsoft has a page about many of the hosters out there that support their technology.  Checkout http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home for an list of hosts and you an see how people reviewed all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but GoDaddy is run by the pervert Bob Parsons. I don't want to support him in any way.

Comment: I understand. My comments about GoDaddy were more to be clear about what GoDaddy is offering. They look great now but when .NET 5 comes out and you aren't able to use it till a year later you probably won't be happy.

Comment: Your link to Microsoft's hosting list was very helpful. I found a host that looks promising (arvixe.com). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of HostGator.  It's simple, unlimited everything (so it seems) and they have bent over backward to accommodate special requests.  And you can't go wrong at their prices, especially for a "playground" type site.  I currently send all my non-enterprise level clients there.  In fact, I'm in the process of moving several dev servers there because they offer all I need at a ridiculously low price.

If money was no object, I'd jump in a heartbeat to AISO.net.  Not only is their virtualized solution amazing and immediate to reboot, but the service includes hourly snapshots....and is 100% on-site wind and solar powered.  How cool is that?

Comment: Very cool actually! Thanks for the advice. The only thing is I need ASP.NET and it doesn't appear as though they offer that.

Comment: ASP.net hosting with ecowin package: http://www.aiso.net/general-hosting-plans.html  Although I see that HostGator only supports .net with dedicated hosting  :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx?ci=9009#details

This is the account that I have used for quite a while.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but GoDaddy is run by the pervert Bob Parsons. I don't want to support him in any way.

Comment: As a former frequent customer, I can also tell you that they charge you for EVERY single add-on and used to be a nightmare to figure out.  The site's gotten easier to use of late, but I now choose to stay away.

Comment: @webworm - pervert?  Other than his embarrassing homepage and silly commercials, has he done anything?

Comment: GoDaddy works with domain squatters/speculators (by sending them data on domains recently expired or searched for by users on GoDaddy.com, and theyalso advertise/sell squatted domains directly on their site). That's enough reason to stay away.

Answer (score 0):

(http://www.linode.com/ || http://www.vpslink.com/) + http://blog.ruski.co.za/page/Install-Mono-on-Ubuntu.aspx == WIN. Just note if your using vpslink you'll need to learn how to tweak apache memory settings down and if your using linode you need to reset the linux password via web interface which you wont notice unless you look around and look for it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, I'll just answer. I recommend GoDaddy, for $5/m you get a lot of capabilities that cover your needs. And ignoring it because you think the owner is a "pervert" just because he uses a sexual-ish marketing approach is childish. If it works it works...

I've used them for 5 years now, but have switched to dedicated servers from them 3 years ago. As far as how fast they upgrade, it's gonna be just about the same for any large host like them because they don't just support .NET or PHP they support both and much more on top of the frameworks so they have to be careful with upgrades.

If you're just gonna have a playground why don't you just run your projects on localhost? If you're on Windows 7 just setup IIS 7.5 add PHP, get SQL Server 2008 Express and MySql and you're all set for all you're playful needs.

Comment: Childish? I simply do not want to give my business to a moral degenerate. I would much rather do business with a company that can sell its services on the merits of its products rather than that of some half naked bimbos. Bottom line, Parsons is a pervert and I don't want to support his "business" model in any way. As for running on localhost that would require a halfway decent upload connection which I do not have. Also, I think it is more cost effective to have someone else take care of sever management. Especially when I am not talking about a mission critical application.

Comment: Well, your opinion is your own and I'm not here to try and change it, I'm merely trying to point out that their price is hard to beat. As for localhost, I mean that you should use it while you're pocking around and figuring things out, not for production use.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using [Aspnix](http://www.aspnix.com/) for our .Net playground and client staging for the past few years. It has all the features we need, and we can live with the occasional downtime as nothing is production. We use the [Shared Personal](http://www.aspnix.com/web-hosting/compare-hosting-plans) at USD7.77 a month.